# Matlab nchoosek problem

Tags: matlab, combinations, performance

My question is Matlab related. There exist a fnct named nchoosek([vector],integer). By using this function I would like to get all 2-elements combinations of the given vector. (i.e nchoosek([1:10000, 2])). This is very slow, as stated in matlab documentation.

The question is : "Is there a faster way to do the same job?".

Thank you for your time I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only 2-element combinations you need, you can use [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html). Note that all two-element combinations up to `N` require `N^2` values, so if Matlab starts paging, the process will be slow.

```
N = 100;
[xx,yy] = ndgrid(1:N,1:N);
allCombinations = [xx(:),yy(:)];
```

Please be aware that the function [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) differs significantly from [nchoosek](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html).
The former returns a double-row vector with all possible N^2 combinations, while the latter is leaving out combinations of two times the same element, as well as combinations where just the order is changed. Leading to just (N^2-N)/2 row elements.

Comment: @conapart: Please consider accepting/upvoting answers that you found useful.