# Combine four items of value one in four random bins, all combinations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax, probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to use [`nchoosek(v,k)`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html?refresh=true) to get all possible combinations of four items of value one distributed randomly over 4 positions. My goal is to get this:

```
[4 0 0 0;
0 4 0 0;
0 0 4 0;
0 0 0 4;
3 1 0 0;
3 0 1 0;
3 0 0 1;
1 3 0 0;
0 3 1 0;
0 3 0 1;
1 0 3 0;
0 1 3 0;
0 0 3 1;
1 0 0 3;
0 1 0 3;
0 0 1 3;
2 2 0 0;
2 0 2 0;
2 0 0 2;
0 2 2 0;
0 2 0 2;
0 0 2 2;
2 1 1 0;
2 1 0 1;
2 0 1 1;
1 2 1 0;
1 2 0 1;
0 2 1 1;
1 1 2 0;
1 0 2 1;
0 1 2 1;
1 1 0 2;
1 0 1 2;
0 1 1 2;
1 1 1 1];
```

However I'm not sure how to input `v` and `k` correctly to achieve this with `nchoosek()`. Whatever I put into `v`, I also get as an output.

```
nchoosek([1,1,1,1], 4)
[1,1,1,1]

nchoosek([1,0,0,0], 4)
[1,0,0,0]

nchoosek([4,0,0,0], 4)
[4,0,0,0]

nchoosek([1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1], 4)
Error using nchoosek (line 29)
The first argument has to be a scalar or a vector.
```

In short I don't get the input and output of `nchoosek(v,k)`. Anybody know how to do this? I [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116928/matlab-nchoosek-problem) [up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624776/matlab-nchoosek-limitation-workaround) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446946/how-to-generate-all-pairs-from-two-vectors-in-matlab-using-vectorised-code) questions here but they didn't help me along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

brute force solution:

```
[d1,d2,d3,d4]=ndgrid(0:4,0:4,0:4,0:4);
d = d1+d2+d3+d4;
i = find(d==4);
[d1(i),d2(i),d3(i),d4(i)]
```

Comment: Thats not too much code to solve it, thanks. I was hoping to just call a function, maybe nchoosek just doesnt do what I thought it did.